# How to add custom HTML form in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there any plugin to add own HTML form in wordpress blog. I want to integrate my own form to wordpress??

Comment: What does the form do? Sneds data somewhere or do You have Your own PHP to manage the data?

Comment: Yes i have my own PHP to manage the data. Form takes input from the users and store data in database

Comment: Of course there is, are you familiar with the theming files that Wordpress uses?

Comment: NO Im new to wordpress David

Answer (score 4):

Here's a blog post explaining how to do that and more: http://shibulijack.wordpress.com/2012/03/18/create-custom-forms-in-wordpress/

Basically you can just add the form html to a page in the page editor (in the text mode) and use your php script url as the form's action attribute.

Comment: That guide doesn't show how to handle forms in WordPress specifically. The only part related to WordPress is that you put some custom HTML on a WordPress page. A better guide would discuss writing a plugin to handle the submitted form data (e.g. which hooks to use) and doing something useful with it.

Comment: Yeah, true, but it does answer the original question and there is nothing wordpress-specific that needs to be done in minimum case. In the comment the author says "i have my own PHP to manage the data" so I assume he already has non-wordpress-specific code to deal with the submission.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use HTML FORMS Plugin to make form with custom HTML
[HTML FORMS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/html-forms/)

Comment: [Link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) are considered very low quality and [can get deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), please put the important parts from the linked resource into the answer body.

Answer (score -1):

checkout the advanced custom fields plugin in which you can simply add forms to your blog 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

Comment: i want to use plugin like pure HTML

Comment: login to your wordpress admin and go to themes and editor there you can edit code if you know PHP

Comment: if you want to add a form in your post you have to edit post.php file or if you want to add a form in your page you have to edit your page under pages menu

Comment: Add html tags inside a form in your php

Comment: its looking fine now where i add my action.php?

Comment: could you please be more specific

Comment: `<form action="add.php" method="post">`where i put the add.php file or the code?

Comment: create html input tags and wrap them under form tag and place them in your add.php file and add your add.php file in wordpress go to pages menu.

Comment: simply go to wordpress login and go to pages menu from there click on add new link and type some html there in you html editor

Comment: when you ask a question please be more specific

Comment: @waqas you need to understand how html forms work and how data is posted to server hope this link will help http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Answer (score -1):

Here is what i did once, im pretty sure that there is a better way to do this though:

```
File: myform.php, in the root of the wordpress folder
<?php
set_include_path(
    get_include_path().PATH_SEPERATOR.
    pathinfo($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'],PATHINFO_DIRNAME));

require('wp-blog-header.php');

header('response: 200 OK');

//change this to match the theme,.. maybe use a function from wordpress instead, i was in a hurry so i didnt make it fancy like that
include "wp-content/themes/twentyten/header.php";
 // Form code here...
include "wp-content/themes/twentyten/footer.php";
?>
```

then make a new page in the wordpress administration area and put this code in the source view:

`<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href='path/to/myform.php';</script>`

But as said, this is kind of a bad way to do it, it got the job done though.

Comment: when i submit form it redirects to myform.php